# Returning a Subclass in Java when a Superclass is Expected

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

**Edit:** This didn't work because I had:

```
class Animal { ... }
class Horse extends Animal { ... }
class Unicorn extends **Animal** { ... }
```

Clearly, this is a typo, and Unicorn is supposed to extend Horse, not animal. And here, I thought I found a hole in Java's polymorphism!

---

Maybe it's just me, but this doesn't make sense. Let's assume I have two classes in Java, Horse and Unicorn (which is a subclass of Horse):

```
public class Horse {
  public String speak() {
    return "Wow, a talking horse!";
  }
}

public class Unicorn extends Horse {
  @Override
  public String speak() {
    return "Unicorns really exist?!";
  }
}
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
public Horse getHorse() {
  return new Unicorn(); // Doesn't compile
}
```

I get the compilation error "Cannot convert from Unicorn to Horse" under Eclipse using JRE or JSE 1.6.

*Why* doesn't it compile? Every unicorn is also a horse, and therefore, I'm returning a valid instance of horse ... aren't I?

My question is really about how polymorphism works in Java. I expect this to work. For what it's worth, this code compiles in .NET 2.0 (maybe that's why I expect it to work in Java, too).

Comment: Can you show us the exact compilation error if you can please?

Comment: It does compile when I copy / paste it though :). So +1 on "what is the exact compilation error".

Comment: Are Horse and Unicorn in your example method really **THOSE** Horse and Unicorn you've mentioned, or do you have others running around on your classpath and accidentally imported those? :-)

Comment: Boy, do I feel sheepish. I had Unicorn extending a different superclass in the Horse hierarchy, and that's why it wasn't compiling.

Comment: @Lukas this is probably it yep.

Comment: @ashes999 that happens a lot too.. so, there is no question, voting to close this :)

Comment: @OscarRyz so THAT'S what you do with "dumb" questions that can't be deleted because they have answers already! I was wondering about that.

Comment: Not really that's the first step. Once closed they can be deleted ( no matter if they have answers or no, btw, I don't use to vote for deletion ), and I don't think this question is "dumb", the prove is, you have found your solution by posting it, it is jut *not a real question* :)

Comment: Aaaah, the good old horses and unicorns running around in the Java forest. I have about 70 of them in my project as well. They tend to get mixed up. That's why I started further subclassing them to `Cindy`, `Swift`, and `Laura` ... ;-) Have a nice weekend guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you write it exactly like this? because you can't have the parentheses in class definitions... e.g.

```
public class Horse() {
```

should be

```
public class Horse {
```

also

```
public class Unicorn extends Horse() {
```

should be

```
public class Unicorn extends Horse {
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I didn't write it with parenthesis. I also edited my question to add the @Override annotation which I use in Unicorn.

Comment: Then, I agree with Simeon, we'll need the compilation error (and probably more code, because what you posted is correct)

Comment: These are in the original post, pasted from Eclipse.

Comment: What's the compilation error, what's the compilation error, what's the compilation error, what's the compilation error, what's the compilation error :)

Comment: Props to you, since you forced me to re-paste this code into Eclipse, which made it compile.

Comment: Not wanting to rant or anything ( I actually upvote this answer ) , but marking this as correct will only cause more confusion to someone who had the same problem the op had, since this wasn't actually the correct solution, the OP was actually inheriting from a different class.

Comment: Ok, I've removed acceptance; I'll edit the original to explain the problem and solution.

Answer (score 2):

Works as expected:

[image: See it in action]

Probably your error, is you have both classes defined in the same source file.

There should be only one public class per file ( or as in my case, many non public )

But, without the exact error message is only speculation.

Comment: Actually, I had them in different files.

Comment: Are you going to buy a license for your copy of Sublime Text? :-)

Comment: Don't know, I just installed it today ( that's why the screenshot ) ... I like it so far, but I'm very used to gVim ( `<esc>:w` is hardwired in my brain ) . Let's see.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Horse {
        public void speak() {
            System.out.println("I'm a horse");
        }
    }

    public static class Unicorn extends Horse {
        public void speak() {
            System.out.println("I'm a unicorn");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getHorse().speak();
    }

    public static Horse getHorse() {
        return new Unicorn();
    }
}
```

It's not fundamentally different from what you claim to be doing, so your problem must be elsewhere.